# Data from a website

Tags: java, web-scraping

I was just sitting and thinking what I should do in programming.

And I thought of a csgo item value calculator.

Then I thought how would I get the prices of the items.

So my question is how do I get information from ex. //
http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma%202%20Case And retrieve the price of the item, which is in this: market_commodity_orders_header_promote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is getting some kind of API tool such as [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and use them to sniff the website. See if its calling any kind of API, and if it is, see if you can take advantage of that API to do what you need to do.

Website Scraping is also a valid option. Either way you should have a look and see which method would work best for you given your problem and experience level.

The most important part is research research research. Google everything before you ask. We all wish you the best of luck!